# Word find style game, distributed letter generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

So, I am working on a word find style game, and how I generate new letters right now just isn't cutting it. I mean it works, however it seems to generate either letters that aren't too often used (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) or generates too many of 1 letter.

Right now I just use a mod based on a random number and chooses based on that, which again it works but is not ideal.

So i have 2 cases

1) On start, it will generate the board with 25 letters which is randomly generated.

2) When a word is found, I remove those letters from the board and generate new letters to replace them

Is there a known algorithm that could based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency generate letters that are most used in words?

I could just do some loop over the existing letters and do a lot looping, letter count. and based on that determine what letter to generate.

I'd prefer something a little less crazy and as well be able to possibly use it for other languages (however not necessary at this point)

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have understood the 2 cases, but what exactly do u want after that?

Comment: Well, bascially trying to create some sort of algorithm that would determine what letter to grab next, whether it needs to be a vowel, a common letter or a letter like Z,V,W etc. Sorry I should of been more clear.

Comment: What is your objective after you generate the new letters? You know the number of possible words to be as big as possible? If not, what exactly?

Comment: Well the game is basically a 6x6 grid of tiles/letters (visually would be like Candy Crush) - which the objective of the game is for the player to find X number of words with X number of letters in the word.  So the next letter should be A) a vowel if there are a low number of vowels B) A common letter or C) a uncommon letter if maybe the density of the common letters is high? But at the same time I don't want like 5 T's

Comment: I figured some sort of density formula would work, but not sure how to make it work within those rules.  Kind of like a SEO word density formula but more for letters - It just might be that I need to do some looping. Another thought I had was give each letter a value, and based on the score of the 36 letters, and based on the score somehow determine the next letter?

Comment: should you always make sure that there exist a word which the user can find? what happens if there is no possible generation of letters such that you provide the user at least one solution?

Comment: Just a note to consider: Letter frequency in common English is not the same as letter frequency for a dictionary.

Comment: right now, I don't always ensure that a word exists, I have yet to run into running out of words to find -  for example, the objective for a given level is to find (5) 4 letter words, since it's kind of like a match 3, if they cannot find a 4 letter word, they can easily find a 2 or 3 letter word, which then takes those letters off the board and new letters drop in from the top giving more opportunities to find a 4 letter word.

Comment: So tracking the number of words would require  a lot of processing. And a word does not have to be inline, you can select any tiles within 1 tile - as opposed to the word having to be horizontal/vertical/diagonal. I would give you a link to the game to see for yourself, but I'm not sure on the rules on doing so

Answer (score 1):

You could create a pool of letters according to frequency, for example the 98 tiles of English letters from [Scrabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions).

When you fill your grid, you remove the picked letters from the pool and place them in the grid. When the player selects a valid word from the grid, do the reverse: Remove the letters from the board and put them back into the pool. Then draw new letters to fill the gaps.

When you want to prefill the grid with some existing words to get the player started, you should also pick letters from the pool.

You can use a simple array for the pool. When you remove a random letter, shorten the array by putting the last element in the place where the picked element was. When you put back elements, just append them to the end of the array.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought about using the Scrabble letter pool, this is a great idea. I will have to give this a try and see how it works. Thanks!